# Memory Error: Unable to allocate array shape ({very large}), solution for windows Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, memory, numpy-ndarray

Though there exist so many of these questions i couldnt find any working solutions for Windows:

I got a large list of lists (of lists):(~30000,48,411)(or even bigger in some cases), which i need as a numpy array for the training of my LSTM model...
Any ideas, how to work it out? (i dont use Linux, just Windows and python 64 bit)

I already tried converting it to np.float32-> still too big!
Then i tried to convert it to np.float16-> "tuple not callable"

The idea was to save and load it via np.memmap(), but therefore i would also need it as a numpy array before. (this format is also needed for the training process, so the goal is to convert it to a np.NdArray)

I even tried to split it into smaller lists (tenths) but still it was unable to allocate.

Comment: Could you post the error(s) you're getting and a MWE?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear for me in what format you have these "lists of lists" and what you mean with "too big" (for your memory, I assume?) but you might want to look into [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/).
With that you can do something like

```
import dask.array as da
import dask
import numpy as np

...
arrays = []
for i in range(nfiles):
    arrays.append(da.from_delayed(read_list(...), shape = (...))
arr = da.stack(arrays)
```

The [dask documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html) has more examples on how to create dask arrays.

In general, if you have data too large for your memory to handle (should not be the case for the 2-3GB of data) the processing will be very slow, so you then best bet is to chunk and then analyze it in chunks.